# i am using Image.getSize from react-native it works fine on android but not in ios when the uri is an empty string

Tags: ios, string, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kCVn.jpg)
source.uri should not be an empty string

```js
 await Image.getSize(
            uri && uri,
            async (width, height) => {
              //success
              //image still exist in the galory

              exist = true;
            },
            (error) => {
              num_messing_files++;
              // Failed
              // image do no exist any more in the galory [ what does exactly X represent]
            }
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the uri is an empty string before calling getSize instead of doing it inside.

```
if(uri){
 await Image.getSize(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I get it but i want use a default value , do you know the default value I can use instead of an empty string? [ for ios ] because it works fine on android.

Comment: the uri in getSize is a required parameter. You are not allowed to pass it an empty string or a null/undefined value. You could either have a "fallback" uri which is used when you don't have the uri or not render the image at all for example. Fallback uri is like the default profile image when a user does not have an avatar for example. Does this answer your question?